# Preloading a Page before Navigating to it WPF

Tags: wpf, navigation

My WPF app consists of a `NavigationWindow`, and then a set of `Page`s defined as separate xaml files.  The NavigationWindow loads and displays the various pages in turn.

My problem is that loading the pages is expensive and may fail.  Thus, I want to preload the page in the background, and then only call `Navigate()` once the page has finished loading.

In pseudocode what I would want is

```
    Page nextPage;
    try
    {
    nextPage = LoadPageFromURI(new URI(...));
    }
    catch
    {
/// constructor of the page threw an exception ... load a different page
    }

    myNavigationWindow.Navigate(nextPage);
```

I can't however find framework functions to do what I want.  Could someone who knows WPF better give me a hand?  Thanks you!

Comment: What pattern do you use? whats the expensive operations? data query or something else?

Comment: This is a small app so it's not using any pattern like MVVM - it's just a NaviationWindow that loads many pages.  The pages themselves do do data query (via ADO.NET) in their constructors ... those operations are long and may fail at times.

Comment: Open to your suggestions if you think the expensive operation should go somewhere else.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `Application.LoadComponent()` will do what I want.

Sample code:

```
Page page;

try
{
    page = (Page) Application.LoadComponent(new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // note error and abort
}

Action action = () => ((NavigationWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).Navigate(page);
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, DispatcherPriority.Normal);
```